# Facebook SDK - access a public album by id without authentication

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I develop an ASP.NET website. It will contain text articles and some of them will contain pictures from my facebook account above and beyond the text. Note that I'm going to use only the public albums from my account.

So I created a sql table and binded the `articles`, the `albums` and the `photos` (in fact the `IDs` of all of them). I already used [facebook api sdk](http://csharpsdk.org/) and it was a great library.

Obviously   any visitor of my website (even he doesn't have a facebook account) mignt be able to see the articles and the **pictures** withount visiting facebook and **without authentication** via facebook `oAuth` to access them.

Well here are the questions:

1) How do I get the photos a public album contains by `album id` and `user id` **without authentication**? (I don't know, maybe I should use the other parameters than album id and user id)

2) How do I get the properties (name, id, etc) of a public album?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With out an access token there's very little you can get from the graph api.
Just try yourself by directing your browser to: `http://graph.facebook.com/YOU_USER_ID`.

You can also check the fields/connections tables in the [User object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), where it says "No access_token required" in the *Permissions* column (3rd) you can get with out a token.

If you want to get other data of yourself and serve it publicly on your site you have two options:

1. Use the [server-side authentication flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/), get a long lived access token (60 days), save that and use it for the following 60 days to get your data from facebook.
   Then, when it gets expired go through the authentication process again.
   It will just be you who needs to go through it, not your users, and only once every 60 days.
2. Log in yourself, authenticate against your app, get all the data and persist it on your db, then just present that to your users.
   You'll need to update things every once in a while.

---

## Edit

The server side authentication flow guide has an example written in php.
It's a simple example which does not cover all scenarios but it's a good start.

I have implemented this in python and java but it's not something that can easily be shared since it spans across multiple requests and states, and so I'll just describe the flow I think that you should use:

1. Inside facebook you go to your canvas app
2. Facebook will make a POST into an iframe with your canvas url
3. In the post data you will get a [signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/), decode it and check if it has an access token, if so check when it expires. If all is good save that token and the auth process is over, otherwise:
4. Redirect the user to the [oAuth dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) along with your redirect url and permissions that you require.
5. After you allow your own app you will be redirected to your "recirect_uri" with the code parameter (in the querystring).
6. Exchange the code for an access token against the facebook servers and save the token.
7. You can then redirect yourself to the canvas app or just stop there.

That should do it for a long lived access token which you can then use for 60 days.

As for persisting your fb data on your own db, it's a pretty trivial operation to save data on a db, and it all depends on what data you want to save, how you need to encode/use it (json, xml, plain text).

For example, let's say you want the display your own photos, then after you get the token (as described above) just query from your server for your photos by issues an http request to: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=XXXXXX`.
You should get a json encoded result, iterate over that and save each picture as a record on your db.

Comment: do you have an example how to do it in asp.net?

Comment: I don't use .net at all, but which part are you referring to? The server side authentication or the persistency of the data?

Comment: Both. So you can give an example in the language you use. It's ok.

Comment: I edited my original answer, hope that will clear things up for you.

Comment: It's seems in the the query `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=XXXXXX` the parameter `me` should be replaced with my real facebook id?

Comment: You can, but "me" is the logged in (to facebook) user, so using your id or "me" is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve list of user's albums you need to issue next GET request to Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=...
```

And to retrieve list of photos:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID?access_token=...
```

But you cannot read user's albums (and photos) without authentication and requesting `user_photos` permission.

According to [`album`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) documentation:

> To read an Album you need
>
> - Any valid access token if it is public and belongs to a [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page)
> - The `user_photos` permission if it belongs to a [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user)
> - The `friend_photos` permission if it belongs to a [User's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) friend

So generally you have only two options to achieve the result you want:

1. Use Facebook Page to store all the [Albums](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/)/[Photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) you want to display on site

   - Read 'em using [Application `access_token`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/).
   - This will allow you to completely bypass authentication flow at all.
2. Use your personal account to store [Albums](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/)/[Photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

   - Authorize application ([client-side](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side)/[server-side](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side)) and grant `user_photos` permissions
   - [Extend `access_token`](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token) for your user and store it
   - Use your personal `access_token` to access your Albums/Photos

Comment: I think I'm going to use facebook page to store the albums. Can you tell me how do I get an album (only one) by its id? And a photo (also only one) by its id?

Comment: And one more thing. To read an album belongs to me (as an User) I must authenticate, but what should I do to avoid visitors must be authenticated to see the albums and the photos?

Comment: @Alex, you can access every object (Album/Photo/User/Page/etc) by it's `id`, just use `https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID` this will return data associated with that object (read the Graph API docs for more details on what data you'll get for different objects).

Comment: You don't require to authenticate your users in both flows I've described (well, except for yourself in the second). Just request the details from Facebook on server-side to not expose `access_token` you'll be using to visitors.